# What's the difference between the users page reputation score and the profile rep

Tags: discussion, reputation

On the users page of this site I have a bold 17 beside my name. Against my name in the other pages I have a reputation of 96. 
What does the 17 mean?

Comment: You have a reputation score of 96 on Stackoverflow. Where do you see a 17? Can you show a picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

17 is the rep you've gained *this week,* the default period. If you look at the top right, you can select a tab for `week`, `month`, `quarter`, `year` or `all`:

> [image]

For example, Jon Skeet currently only has 2,470 on the weekly page despite the fact he's approaching half a million overall.

For `week`, you do indeed have 17:

> [image]

If you select `all`, it gives you your overall rep of 96:

> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Every Stack Exchange Network site has a unique reputation score.